# error: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dependencies, android-room

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
> Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
  at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
  Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

  at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.validateKotlinAndJavaHasSameTargetCompatibility(Tasks.kt:797)
  at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin_common(Tasks.kt:722)
  at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin_common(Tasks.kt:530)
  at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.executeImpl(Tasks.kt:450)
  at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:417)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:45)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.execute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:26)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:93)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:57)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:54)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:54)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:166)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
  at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:76)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:42)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:31)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)

build.gradle(app):

`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.secrets_gradle_plugin' version '0.4'

    //
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

    //
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'


}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.appnews'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appnews"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
        buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"${properties.getProperty('API_KEY')}\""

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'

    //Navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.0'

    //Room
    def room_version = "2.2.5"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"


    //Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5"

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.android.car.ui:car-ui-lib:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    //splash screen
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.5.0"


    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'


    //Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    //Tests
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

correction error build.gradle(app)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.